# Asp.Net MVC Null Reference Exception with SignInManager upon invalid login

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I've noticed a pretty strange bug with my code, where when I attempt to log in to my site with an invalid email address, I get a Null Reference Exception.

More specifically, it says that this is what is null:

```
 var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user.UserName,
                                                                model.Password,
                                                                model.RememberMe,
                                                                shouldLockout: false);
```

Normally, it should just return the login view to the user with an error message stating that the email address is invalid.

I think it has something to do with the `user.Username` section of the PasswordSignInAsync, as that is usually `user.Email` but I changed it in order to have different UserNames and Emails.

Is there a reason this happens, or should I just try checking for an invalid email and return the view manually?

Comment: Can you add _stack trace_ of exception?

Comment: Why is "UserName" coming form "user" and the other fields from "model"? How does "user" get created?